# Pickle error: AttributeError: Can't get attribute on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: python, pickle

I am having a problem with pickle in python

```
import time,sys,pickle

print("welcome to vom")

#what if rooms are mycelium that connect tothe vom pokeballs

with open('test.p', 'rb') as f:
    rooms = pickle.load(f)

class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.intro=None
        self.startroom=None
        self.objects=[]
        self.doors=[]
        self.start=False
        self.verbs={}
        self.Class=None

class Object(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.intro=None
        self.verbs={}

class Key(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.link=link

def  gorl():
    global player
    
    while True:
        print("what mode do you wanna be on the astral plane globally or local")
        print("(type global or local for a response)")
        myInput=input(">>> ")

        if myInput=="global" or myInput=="local":
            break

    player.mode=myInput

def gorp():
    global player

    while True:
        print("do you wanna play as a god or a player")
        print("(type god or player for a response)")
        myInput=input(">>> ")

        if myInput=="god" or myInput=="player":
            break

    player.pmode=myInput

mykeyinstructions=["key"]

def addtoroom(numx):
    global mykeyinstructions
    global rooms

    print("type the verbs you want to apply for your room (for example yo0u could type smell look hear) ")
    myList=input(">>> ").split()

    for x in myList:
        print(x)
        print("what do you want to happen when this verb is comitted?")
        print("type add function if you want a local function otherwise type what you want the computer to say")
        myInput=input(">>> ")
        rooms[numx].verbs[x]=myInput

    print("and then what? add objects and monsters and wizards to your room... by typing create x")
    print("type help for more info type create to add an object") 
    
    while True:
        myInput=input(">>>")

        if myInput=="help":
            print("you can create objects by typing create x")
            print("if you wanna create a key type create key x")
            print("type exit when you have finished creating your room")

        instructions=myInput.split(" ")

        myList=instructions[:]
        del myList[0]

        #print(instructions)
        #print(instructions[0]=="create")


        if instructions[0]=="create" and len(instructions)>1:
            if instructions[1] not in mykeyinstructions:
                print("you are forging a new object right now...")

                rooms[numx].objects.append(Object(" ".join(myList)))
                print("what should be the intro for your object?")
                rooms[numx].objects[-1].intro=input(">>> ")

                print("type the verbs you want to apply to your objects (for example yo0u could type smell look hear)")
                myList=input(">>> ").split()

                for x in myList:
                    print(x)
                    print("what do you want to happen when this verb is comitted?")
                    print("type add function if you want a local function otherwise type what you want the computer to say")
                    myInput=input(">>> ")
                    rooms[numx].objects[-1].verbs[x]=myInput

            elif instructions[0]=="key":
                del myList[1]
                rooms[numx].objects.append(Key(" ".join(myList)))

        if myInput=="exit":
            print("you are quitting the game.")
            pickle.dump(rooms,open("test.p","wb"))
            sys.exit()

def createroom(start=False,status="local"):
    global rooms

    print("welcome to the abyss")
    print("what you wanna do?")

    if len(rooms)==0:
        print("0>> ponder on the abyss of the energy")
        print("1>> create a room")
        print("type the number of the option")
        myinput=input(">>> ")

        while True:
            if myinput=="0":
                print("you ponder on the abyss of the energy...")
                print("the aliens come down they are the energy they send you to a separate astral plane") 
                print("you win the game.")
                sys.exit()

            elif myinput=="1":
                print("you create a room what would you like it to be officially called?")
                rooms.append(Room(input(">>> ")))
                rooms[-1].start=True
                rooms[-1].status=status
                break

    else:
        print("0>> ponder on the abyss of the room")
        print("1>> create a room")
        print("type the number of the option")
        myinput=input(">>> ")

        while True:
            if myinput=="0":
                print("you ponder on the abyss of the room...")
                print("the aliens come down they are the energy they send you to a separate astral plane") 
                print("you win the game.")
                sys.exit()

            elif myinput=="1":
                print("you create a room what would you like it to be officially called?")
                rooms.append(Room(input(">>> ")))
                break

    print("what next? ")
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print("add an intro for your room")
    intro=input(">>> ")

    rooms[-1].intro=intro

    addtoroom(-1)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mode=None
        self.pmode=None
        self.intro=None
        self.bronze=0
        self.silver=0
        self.gold=0

player=Player()

time.sleep(3.0)

gorl()

#anyone can edit rooms edit room mode needs to be created
#move up or down or left or right on the astral plane for standard connection of rooms

if player.mode=="global": #the difference between global or local is the fact that the doors of the mazes can link up to other player's stories in the mazes for global mode
    print("welcome to the astral plane we will now log you onto the game")
    gorp()

    if len(rooms)==0:
        print("the room is now empty all you see is the white abyss what do you wanna do?")
        createroom(True,"global")

    else:
        print("do you wanna enter a astral plane or create a new one?")
        print("1>> new story")
        print("2>> log into an old story")

        myinput=input(">>>")

        if myinput=="1":
            time.sleep(1.0)
            #print("ok welcome to your new story...")
            createroom()
        else:
            pass
        

if player.mode=="local":
    print("welcome to story mode we will now log you onto the game")
    gorp()

    if len(rooms)==0:
        print("the room is now empty all you see is the white abyss what do you wanna do?")
        createroom(True)

    else:
        print("do you wanna enter an story or create a new one?")
        print("1>> new story")
        print("2>> log into an old story")

        myinput=input(">>>")

        if myinput=="1":
            time.sleep(1.0)
            print("ok welcome to your new story...")
            createroom()

        else:
            pass #enter new story mode

        myinput=input(">>>")
```

then I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/macla/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/vom.py", line 8, in <module>
    rooms = pickle.load(f)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Room' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

can anyone help?

Comment: "Can anyone fix this bug" is a title that could be used for every question here. Use the space in the title to describe the specific technical problem in a way that's unique to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading the pickle *before* defining all of your classes. The `pickle.load` will occur before Python has had a chance to parse and execute the rest of your class definitions.

Typically, you want to avoid running any real code at module level; instead, run that sort of "main program" code at the bottom in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. Thus:

```
import ...

class Room: ...

class Object: ...

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("welcome to vom")
    
    with open('test.p', 'rb') as f:
        rooms = pickle.load(f)

    player=Player()

    time.sleep(3.0)

    gorl()
    ...
```

Comment: Can you explain with is is necessary to load the class? I am trying to find why this is necessary but no one explains why. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)  "Similarly, when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and data are not pickled along with them." I can't understand what goes under the hood with `pickle`.

Comment: At the point when you call `pickle.load`, pickle will read serialized data (pickled data) and attempt to create objects from it. For class instances, the pickled data will contain the full name of the class (module name + class name) and the instance data, but not the code of the class nor data stored in the class itself. pickle.load will look up the classes by name, create an empty instance and then restored the saved data to the instance. Thus, the class definition needs to exist at the time you call pickle.load.

Comment: With regards to "create an empty instance" if I save an instance (with `pickle.dump`), then modify the `__init__` method of the class and finally load the instance (with `pickle.load`) the instance attributes are not changed. Nevertheless, if I change the class attributes, these changes appear when loading the instance. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `__init__` isn’t called. `__new__` is used instead, then the attributes are directly set on the instance. Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

Comment: If you want to understand pickle better, you may find the [`pickletools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html) module helpful, as well as the source code of the [pickle module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/pickle.py) itself.